# how to create schema of a delta table in databricks by using column names from text file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a text file which stores all the column names
**for ex:** text file contains following data

```
table1=['column1','2_column2','3_column3']
table2=['column4','5_column5','6_column6']
```

I need to fetch all the values and create a schema for tables mentioned in the text file. and also some of the the columns starts with number as well as mentioned above.
**output needed:**

```
table1 = StructType([
        StructField("column1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("2_column2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("3_column3", StringType(), True)
    ]

table2 = StructType([
        StructField("column4", StringType(), True),
        StructField("5_column5", StringType(), True),
        StructField("6_column6", StringType(), True)
    ]
```

all the columns will be **string type**.

how to achieve this using python/pyspark?

Comment: what is StructType and StructField? can you add details about it

Answer (score 0):

```
table1 = ['column1', '2_column2', '3_column3']
data = []
for i in table1:
    data.append(f'StructField({i}, StringType(), True)')
table1 = f'StructType({data})'
print(table1)
>>> StructType(['StructField(column1, StringType(), True)', 'StructField(2_column2, StringType(), True)', 'StructField(3_column3, StringType(), True)'])
```